# PHP MySQL Weird Update Problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a heap based table in MySQL that I am trying to update via PHP, but for some reason, the updates do not seem to be taking place.

Here is my test code:

```
<?php
$freepoints[] = 1;
$freepoints[] = 2;
$freepoints[] = 3;
foreach ($freepoints as $entrypoint) {
$query = "update gates set lane='{$entrypoint}' where traffic > 50 limit 50";
echo "$query\n";
mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_affected_rows()."\n";
}
?>
```

This outputs the following:

```
update gates set lane='1' where traffic > 50 limit 50
50
update gates set lane='2' where traffic > 50 limit 50
50
update gates set lane='3' where traffic > 50 limit 50
50
```

In the database to start with lanes 1/2/3 had 0 records and lanes 4/5/6 had 100 records. From this I am expecting all 6 lanes to now have 50 records each. However when I look lanes 4/5/6 still have 100 records and 1/2/3 still have 0 records.

When I copy the query "update gates set lane='1' where traffic > 50 limit 50" into phpMyAdmin it works absolutely fine, so any ideas why it isn't working in my PHP script when mysql_affected_rows is saying it has updated 50 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add ORDER BY clause
2. you are always rewriting with the same data. you need to specify WHERE with lane to update another rows

Comment: I changed query to the following but still doesn't work:  update gates set lane='{$entrypoint}' where traffic > 50 and lane != '{$entrypoint}' order by lane limit 50

Comment: Oh now I feel such an idiot when I realise the issue you're saying. I changed query as follows and it works fine now: "update gates set lane='{$entrypoint}' where traffic > 50 and lane > '{$entrypoint}' limit 50". Thank you!

Comment: even it's work for you now - i advice to always specify ORDER to get obvious results.